# UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated: crash in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios6

The code below works fine in iOS 4 and 5 but crashes in iOS 6 with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I'd appreciate any help in troubleshooting it. This code is being called in a `UITableViewController` that handles my app's search logic:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

The way I add the `tableView` is similar and doesn't crash when called:

```
SearchTVC *searchTable = [[SearchTVC alloc] init];
searchTable.detailViewController = self.detailViewController;

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:searchTable animated:NO];
```

What could be the problem?

***EDIT**

Interestingly the crash doesn't occur if I use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` (`YES` rather than `NO`). But of course this defeats the purpose of using a custom pop animation.

Comment: More details about the crash would help; I'm reminded of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584607/how-to-prevent-crash-on-cancel-of-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/11588677#11588677

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know my question was vague, but I didn't have much else to go off of. I knew the line `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];` was the problem but I couldn't figure out why. Then I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995146/frustrating-uiwebview-delegate-crash-issue) and the first answer suggested I make my search table an instance variable rather than creating a new one every time I want to present it, and that actually worked. It must be a memory issue that I can't wrap my head around.

***tl;dr*** :

**Make sure the `UIViewController` that's being pushed and popped is an instance variable.**

Comment: Love the TLDR version. It made the most sense to me, and more importantly... worked.

Answer (score 7):

Check whether you have a line like the following somewhere in your view controller code:

```
self.navigationController.delegate=self;
```

If so, then you must set it back

```
self.navigationController.delegate=nil;
```

before you say

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Otherwise, `popViewControllerAnimated` will first deallocate the delegate and then try to call it - resulting in a crash.

Comment: resetting the navigation controller's delegate appears to need to happen in `viewWillDisappear:`. Doing it in `viewDidDisappear:` seems to work sometimes, but not all the time, and `viewWillDisappear:` still allows the delegate to control any custom transitions.

Comment: Many thanks. It would have taken me a long time to find this. It's a very obnoxious time-bomb based crash deep in iOS internal stack.

Answer (score 1):

Though super late to party... Hope this might help someone in future.
I opened a very old code...

`Enabling ARC mode` and then resolving all the compiler warnings/error fixed it automatically.