# Anything to be aware of that causes instability when running on iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, iphone-5

I'm not sure if this is going to be a useful question/thread, as I dont have any concrete examples or snippets to provide.

All I know is that I have been testing my app via simulator (the Retina 4") with no problems.
Then when I deploy to a device (via ad-hoc) i see stability issues, like choppiness in animation, general sluggishness, and occasional crashes due to various reasons (mostly it seems to be somewhere with navigating between views).

On previous iPhone device versions things seem to run fine.

The app has a couple of files where the memory is manually managed. All other files are subject to the automatic memory cleanup.

Comment: Try restarting your iPhone....

Comment: i'm going to go with this suggestion and see if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570799/uinavigationcontroller-popviewcontrolleranimated-crash-in-ios-6

Comment: Nah, this can't be it. I'm already doing all that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt...use Instruments!  Let it help you isolate where problems are in slow animations.  Keep in mind that because there is more real estate on an iPhone 5, it must load more resources, for example, in a TableView.

Comment: This is the best answer, and not to mention a good one too. I totally forgot about the instruments. As far the closing of this question due to "ambiguity", whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Slow animations? Watch the WWDC 2012 video on speeding up animations. Basically what you're experiencing is exactly what you can expect when you switch from the simulator to your device. The simulator is your computer which is very fast and has lots of memory. The device isn't, isn't, and doesn't. This is why you test on the device. There's nothing "wrong" with the phone.