# application crashes when popViewControllerAnimated animation set NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

Its look strange for me Application crashes for me when navigate to back.

```
// backButtonAction.
-(void)backAction:(id)sender{
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Its really strange when set Animation YES its not crashes, When set No for animation its crasheing.

Crash message is also not displaying for me directly going to app delegate main thread..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570799/uinavigationcontroller-popviewcontrolleranimated-crash-in-ios-6

Comment: show the code how you are pushing viewController.

Comment: NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“SecondViewController”];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:NO];