# Application crash when hook popViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, objective-c

I hook the method popViewControllerAnimated .sometime i receive the crash
I need to resolve the crash but I'm stuck here so any help is highly appreciated.

```
Incident Identifier: 19B778C7-623F-40D4-871E-EDF3C16240DB
CrashReporter Key:   TODO
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Version:         8.2.2 (1814)
Code Type:       ARM-64
Parent Process:  launchd [1]
Date/Time:       2017-07-02 14:41:07 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:  104
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x10
Crashed Thread:  0
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                               -[UINavigationController _customTransitionController:] + 320
2   UIKit                               _popViewControllerNormal + 412
3   UIKit                               -[UINavigationController _popViewControllerWithTransition:allowPoppingLast:] + 644
4   UIKit                               -[UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:] + 572
5   METDyldCollection                   -[UINavigationController(KMNavigationBarTransition) km_popViewControllerAnimated:] (UINavigationController+KMNavigationBarTransition.m:94)
6   imeituan                            -[UINavigationController(HTKPushPopHook) pushpop_hook_popViewControllerAnimated:] (UINavigationController+HTKPushPopHook.m:50)
7   METDyldCollection                   __67-[SAKTransitionSafeNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:]_block_invoke (SAKTransitionSafeNavigationController.m:75)
8   METDyldCollection                   -[SAKTransitionSafeNavigationController addTransitionBlock:] (SAKTransitionSafeNavigationController.m:167)
9   METDyldCollection                   -[SAKTransitionSafeNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:] (SAKTransitionSafeNavigationController.m:73)
10  METDyldCollection                   -[MLNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:] (MLNavigationController.m:51)
```

Comment: Please refer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570799/uinavigationcontroller-popviewcontrolleranimated-crash-in-ios-6

Comment: Can you show the code where it crashes?